# How to develop a Smart Magnifier using the mobile camera?

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera

I would like to use the mobile camera and develop a smart magnifier that can zoom and freeze-frame what we are viewing, so we don't have to keep holding the device steady while we read. Also should be able to change colors as given in the image in the link below.

https://lh3.ggpht.com/XhSCrMXS7RCJH7AYlpn3xL5Z-6R7bqFL4hG5R3Q5xCLNAO0flY3Fka_xRKb68a2etmhL=h900-rw

Since i'm new to android i have no idea on how to start, do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: In abstract, you need to render each frame in `SurfaceView` with Camera and then you can get `Bitmap` image from buffer stream.Now you can perform zoom or color operations on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar and published it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andyscan.andylens). I  have to warn you though, this is not a task to start Android development with. Not because of development skills, the showstopper here is a need for massive amount of devices to test it on.

Basically, two reasons:

1. Camera API is quite complicated and the different HW devices behave differently. Forget about using emulator, you would need a bunch of real HW devices.
2. There is a new API, Camera2 for platform 21 and higher, and the old Camera API is deprecated (kind of 'in limbo' state).

I have posted some custom Camera code on [GitHub here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/AndyCam), to show some of the hurdles involved.

So the easiest way out in your situation would be to use [camera intent](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents) approach, and when you get your picture back (it is a jpeg file) just decompress it and zoom-in to the center of the resulting bitmap.

Good Luck

Comment: I totally agree that its not a task to start Android development with.Anyways thank you so much.I will go through your code and give it a try.Hope you'll post the completed code after testings are done.Thanks again :)

Comment: It is only a half of AndyLens app, the Camera handler. But most of it can be accomplished easily through Camera Intent (it is safer, intent will always work). And the picture zooming can be done using different forms of animation, see http://youtu.be/XNF8pXr6whU or search 'Chet Haase' on YouTube DevBytes. If you want to get up to speed with Android in general, I would definitely recommend  https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853.